# Karma: Uncaught Error: jasmine.Suite() required

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm new to Karma and I've just followed their install and configuration tutorial.
I started the Karma using:

```
karma start my.conf.js
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.23 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket ZQsMdsAHICuCrj3MXcDz with id 90144583
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 7) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: jasmine.Suite() required
  at local/Projects/webserver/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2294
```

I'm running node-express and anguler+requirejs.
Any idea why this error happens? How it can be fixed?

Thanks

EDIT:
My my.conf.js file:

// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Sep 18 2014 18:11:55 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

```
// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: './',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'public/test/test-main.js',
    {pattern: 'public/js/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'public/lib/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'public/test/**/*Spec.js', included: false}
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
        'public/js/main.js'
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false
```

});
};

Comment: could you paste your my.conf.js

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your 'it' block inside describe block and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by reinstalling karma, jasmine and karma-jasmine and karma-requirejs. For some reason, it didn't work at first.